# What to do if i keep getting error: Local variable j defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, database, counter, keylistener

i am trying to read how many rows are there on the location (i) and display separated by enter which one is displayed at the moment(j) - example 1 of 15 when pressed enter will display 2 of 15
here's part of code which causes error:

```
int i = 0;
        int j = 0;


        try {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Location = 'REC1U'");
            while(rs.next()) {
                i++;
            }
            rs.next();
            tfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        j++; // <--- this is causing above error
                        String l = String.valueOf(j);

                        count.setText(l);
                    }
                }

                });
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
```

i have tried to make it final just to try to get rid of it but it wouldn't work anyways...

Comment: One workaround would be to wrap it in an AtomicReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object that has a counter inside which is final. For example:

```java
final AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger(0);

//...
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    j.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: I will mark it as good answer as it gets rid of the error and actually it shows 0 on the screen but i think i missed something else in my code as it wont increment while pressing enter. Thanks :)